# Why does Vite.js can not find my imported module?

Tags: reactjs, vite, react-typescript

I'm trying to setup Vite with React to create an app. I'm using my own components library, which I import as a node module. I'm using a different import for types (as I prefer not to mix components and types), but when I try to import a type Vite shows this error:

```js
Cannot find module 'library/types' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

If I use `create-react-app` these imports work well. Where did I go wrong?

This is the code for exporting types in my library `package.json`:

```json
 "typesVersions": {
    "*": {
        "types": [
            "./dist/lib/types/index.d.ts"
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the folder structure of the library:

```
|-package.json
|-src
|-dist
|   |-types
|   |-index.d.ts
|   |-lib.es.js
|   |-lib.umd.js
|   |-index.css
```

And I want to import these types like this:

```js
import type { ThemeTypes } from "library/types"
```

Thanks for your help!